# Dynamic NewObjectArray of Bitmap Images in JNI

Tags: android, c++, opencv, bitmap, java-native-interface

So I `std::vector<cv::Rect> boundRect` from which I have to create an array of `Mat` Images and through `JNI` use it in Android code.

This is the code that works if I have to send a single Bitmap Image.

```
Mat dst= orignal_image(rectObject);
jclass java_bitmap_class = (jclass)env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "getConfig", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject bitmap_config = env->CallObjectMethod(bitmap, mid);
jobject _bitmap = mat_to_bitmap(env,dst,false,bitmap_config);
AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        return _bitmap;
```

How can I create the `jobjectarray` of Bitmap images?

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: @Michael Editted my question

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _"send"_.

Comment: @Michael Is it clear to you now?

Comment: Err, with `NewObjectArray()` of course. You've answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it -

```
jobjectArray strarr = env->NewObjectArray(sizeRect, (jclass)env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap"), 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeRect; i++)
    {
        dst = mbgra(boundRect[i]);
        jclass java_bitmap_class = (jclass)env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
        jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "getConfig", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
        jobject bitmap_config = env->CallObjectMethod(bitmap, mid);
        jobject _bitmap = mat_to_bitmap(env,dst,false,bitmap_config);
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmap);
        env->SetObjectArrayElement(strarr, i, _bitmap);
    }
    return strarr;
```